# AUDIT_FAILURE when running Get-PSDrive from remote system

Tags: powershell

We run a script to connect to a remote server over a VPN and copy a file.

First we created a password file:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content C:\Scripts\password.txt
```

And then we use that password file to map a drive with `Get-PSDrive` and copy a file:

```
Get-PSDrive Q | Remove-PSDrive
$password = Get-Content C:\Scripts\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("DOM\user", $password)
New-PSDrive -name "Q" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\192.168.1.100\Test -Credential $credential -Persist
Copy Q:\*.* C:\Scripts
```

This works, but we see AUDIT_FAILUREs in the event log which our monitoring system is flagging. It tries to use local credentials from where the script runs, which aren't valid and therefore causes the AUDIT_FAILURE.

Cannot see why we get this issue.

Comment: Is the script running as the same user that created the Password file?  Also, is the script running on the same system that the password file was created from?

Comment: Yes and yes. There are no actual issues connecting, other than we see attempts to connect using local credentials of system where script runs which fail. Credential file works fine.

Comment: try using the credential switch on the actual copy command:  Copy-Item Q:\*.* C:Scripts -Credential $credential

Comment: @ShamusBerube that didn't have any impact. We've decided to put in a process to ignore these AUDIT_FAILURES, which isn't great, but this wasn't getting anywhere.